# Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring mcv

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc and I can't get a button to work, when I click on the button it says: Request method 'Post' not supported.

This is my html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cart</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body th:object="${picture}">

        <form method="post">
            Authhor: <label th:text="*{ownerName}" /><br />
            Title: <label th:text="*{title}" /><br />
            Description: <label th:text="*{description}" /><br />
            Price: €<label th:text="*{price}" /><br />
            Product: <select th:field="${productss}" th:remove="all-but-first">
                <option th:each="product : ${productss}" 
                        th:value="${product.id}" th:text="${product.name + '   (+ €' + product.price + ')'}">Productname</option>
            </select><br />
            <img width="250" heigth="250" th:src="*{plainURL}"/><br />
            <button align="right" class="btn" type="submit" name="add" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">Add to shopping cart</span></button><br />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the method I want to execute:

```
@RequestMapping(value = IMAGE, method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"add"})
public String add(HttpSession session, Model model) {
    System.out.println("its working!");
    return "/image/5";
}
```

I know this questen is posted a lot, but I can't find a working solution for me.

Comment: Add a `action` attribute in form `<form method="post" action="/some_url">`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified any target for the form. Add "action" and the path you have added in `@RequestMapping`. Add "double quotes" to your value.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "image", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"add"})
```

If you don't mention the `action` in your form, it will hit the URL currently in your browser URL bar. In that case, url should be able to handle post as well. For example, if you have `localhost/app/addTocart` then you should be handling two methods. With `method=post` and other with `method=get`